# Tabs are not working

Tags: php, html, ajax, tabs

i have small project under which i have two tabs Fahrzeuge and Edit-Fahrzeuge inside a containers. And i want only 1 tab container to be visible at the same time. I try to do the following code but its now working. In Fahrzeuge tab container i have image. When you click on that image the Fahrzeuge tab container should be hidden and Edit-Fahrzeuge tab container be visible. I have submit button,reset and cancel button inside  Edit-Fahrzeuge tab container. When you click Submit button the current tab container should be hide and the Fahrzeuge tab container should be visible. Any help? Thanks.
Here is my code:

dashboard.php

```
<?php
chdir('..');
include 'constant/const_system.inc.php';
include 'functions/ad_json.inc';
include 'functions/ad_formulare.inc';

$page['doctype'] = true;
// -- BUTTON ERSTELLEN ---------------------------------------------------------
$page['button'] = array(
    0 => array( 'Submit','pfeil2r','',''),
    1 => array( 'Reset','pfeil2r','#resetFilter',''),
    2 => array( 'Cancel','pfeil2r','#cancelFilter',''),
);

$mysql_host='192.168.1.52';
$mysql_user='www1';
$mysql_pass= 'upe0goo';
$mysql_db='adsetest';
$myConnection = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass);
mysql_select_db($mysql_db,$myConnection);

$param = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);

$return = array();

// Your Code

function showVehicleTab(){
    $param['aktion'] = 'get-widget-vehicle';
}

function showVehicleTabEdit(){
    $param['aktion'] = 'get-widget-vehicle-edit';
}


if($param['aktion'] == 'save-widget-vehicle')
{
        //Save into the dB
    $param['aktion'] = 'get-widget-vehicle';
}

if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle')
{
    $data = array();

    $opts = !empty($param['filterOpts']) ? $param['filterOpts'] : array();

      $tmp = array();
      foreach ($opts as $opt) {
            $tmp[] = '"'.$opt.'"';
      }
             $query = 
          'SELECT Fahrzeuge.dsnr,name
           FROM Fahrzeuge
           INNER JOIN ohne_fahrzeuge ON Fahrzeuge.dsnr = ohne_fahrzeuge.dsnr
           WHERE Fahrzeuge.name IN ('.implode(",", $tmp).')';

      $result = mysql_query($query, $myConnection);

      /*while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($row['name'] == 'Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder')
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM amo_bilder_live l LEFT JOIN afzdaten a ON l.dsnr_afzdaten = a.dsnr WHERE l.dsnr_afzdaten IS NULL';
            //get result...
            // $row['number'] = $result
        }
        $data[] = $row;
        }
        */


    $page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
        1   => array( 'Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
        0   => array( 'Edit-Fahrzeug','enabled',$page['script'],'','showVehicleTabEdit()'), 
    );

    $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-fahrzeuge']).'</div>
                '.CreateMessage().'
                <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">
                <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="tab1" class="tab" style="display:block">
                    <table id="fahrzeuge">
                    <thead>
                        <a href="#"><img id="filtered" src="images/button/wl_stift_gruen.gif"></a>
                                    <tr>
                                    //Build your List
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    $return = array(
        'status' => 1,
        'html'  => $html
    );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();

}

if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle-edit')
{
    $page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
        1   => array( 'Fahrzeug','enabled',$page['script'],'','showVehicleTab()'),
        0   => array( 'Edit-Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),   
    );

    $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-fahrzeuge']).'</div>
                    '.CreateMessage().'
                    <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">
                        <table id="fahrzeuge-edit" >
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder" id="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder" checked />
                            <label for="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder">Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" id="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" checked />
                            <label for="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis">Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis</label><br>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" id="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" checked />
                            <label for="Fahrzeuge mit Fehlern">Fahrzeuge mit Fehlern</label><br>

                      <input type="checkbox" name="Herausforderungen" id="Herausforderungen" checked />
                            <label for="Herausforderungen">Herausforderungen</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        </table>
                        '.CreateButton($page['button']).' 
                    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    $return = array(
        'status' => 1,
        'html'  => $html
    );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();
}

if($param['aktion'] == 'open-window-new-widget')
{
    //$return['html'] = ''
    //Return HTML of "Add-Widget-Window"
}


if($param['aktion'] == 'add-new-widget')
{
    //Save the new Widget for the user
    //Return OK / 1
    //On JS: Hide / Close "Add-Widget-Window"
}

//echo $param['jsonp'] ."(". json_encode($return) .");";
?>
```

dashboard.inc.php

```
 <?php
// -- REGISTER ERSTELLEN -------------------------------------------------------

$page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
    1   => array( 'Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
    0   => array( 'Edit-Fahrzeug','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),   
);

$page['register-news'] = array(
    1   => array( 'News','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
);



// -- HTML AUSGEBEN ------------------------------------------------------------
$page['content'] .= '

<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="welcome" style="width:538px;margin:0 0 20px 0;padding:10px;">
                Willkommen Rahul!
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="border:5px solid red; margin:0 0 20px 0;padding:10px;">
                SYSTEM-INFO
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


    <table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
        <tr>
            <td id="fahrzeuge">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
        <tr>
            <td id="fahrzeuge-edit">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
            '.CreateMessage().'
            <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">
                Content
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>';
?>
```